# Bootstrap 5 Lightbox Unwanted Scroll Bars

Tags: bootstrap-5, lightbox

I have a website running on Bootstrap 5.3 with Lightbox. When the modal is opened the page itself scrolls. I can't figure out how to fix this so the page doesn't scroll.

Example here:
[Example](https://dev.honeycuttmedia.com)

I've tried to change max-heights within the modal settings for modal-fullscreen with no luck.

Comment: Your modal-body class has `overflow-y:scroll`,  remove that and add `overflow:hidden`. I think this will help.
Also there is a`max-height:100%` to the image, if you reduce that to 96~97%, the image will look good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `modal-body` class has `overflow-y:scroll`, remove that and add `overflow:hidden`. I think this will help. Also there is a `max-height:100%` to the image, if you reduce that to 96~97%, the image will look good

With `overflow-y:scroll` property
[image]

When `overflow:hidden` and image size is 96%
[image]